# What is an ideal way to handle retries for api call and token refresh in typescript?

Tags: typescript, express, authentication, axios

The application I'm working on has to fetch fresh access_token from server of apps like hubspot, google etc.

Now the retry strategies I've come across till now cover normal api calls but in my case I have to handle 2 cases:

1. Retries for fetching access_token in case that call fails.
2. Retry api calls (with access_token in headers) for some specific status codes for bad request or auth related issues.

Now when case 2 happens, I'll issue a new token from case 1. The issue is I can think of multiple ways it can end up either in infinite loop (which I can easily handle by limiting retries) or unnecessary api calls, **which increases latency** for final response needed.

Wanted to know what would be a good strategy to handle retries in such case.

**Note:** We use axios client for all api calls.